# Is there a proof that $|(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}| = \phi(n)$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I was reading a proof of Fermat's Little Theorem that used the multiplicative group of integers modulo n. It stated that $|(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}| = \phi(n)$ (or rather that $|(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*}| = p-1$). Is this by definition or is there a proof for this independent of the Little Theorem?

Here's the paper (the proof starts at the end of page 5): http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Momkus.pdf

Thanks

Comment: What you asl about is not written there. Is the link correct?

Comment: Yes. Right after it proves that $G$ satisfies the axioms of a group it says "Observe that $|G| = p-1$" on page 6. The question is really independent of the paper though, I just added it in case.

Comment: They define $G$ to be $\{ \bar 1, \bar 2,\ldots \overline{p-1}\}\subset \Bbb Z/p\,$ so $\,|G| = p-1$ is  obvious.

Comment: By definiiton, $\phi(n)$ is the number of integers $k$, $1\leq k\leq n$, such that $\gcd(k,n)=1$. Since $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ consists precisely of the congruence classes $k+n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd(k,n)=1$, the equality is immediate. That these are the elements does not depend on the Little Theorem: if there is a solution to $kx\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, then $n|km-1$ for some $m$, hence $1=km+rn$ for some $m,r$, so $\gcd(k,n)=1$. Conversely, if $\gcd(k,n)=1$, then there exist $r,s$ such that $kr+ns=1$, so $kr\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ so $k$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.